# Create and share Magnolia CMS content

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I would like to know if it is possible to create some content outside the page and share this content between pages/sites?

What I would like to do is create products content(name, description etc.) and based on that content create component "product catalog". Now when I edit the page I take my new "catalog component" which gives me access to the previously created products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is absolutely possible. Typically you would do this by writing your own content app as described in [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/My+first+content+app). You can also have look at "Contacts" app for example of the code if documentation is not enough for you.
Alternatively you can look at forge for existing modules that would do what you want. There is for example [shop module](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Shop+module) that has some product catalog in it already.

HTH,
Jan